# How to save multiple selected photos separately to upload to a server in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, onactivityresult

I have had a problem for weeks and still can not solve, did a lot of research and tested many codes, but nothing solved. I will explain my problem in detail.

I am making an application where in a layout there would be three or more clickable photos, I am using the “ArthurHub / Android-Image-Cropper” image cropping library, the steps are:

> 1. Click on the image, which gives the option to open the image gallery to select a photo or take a new photo, after that I can crop
>      the selected image.
>
>    2. Select the second photo, do the same as the previous one, thereafter.
>    3. Upload the photos to the server.

Steps 1 is working correctly, the problem arises when I try to select from the second image.
What I'm using: I'm using two classes: the one that requests the images and the one that returns:
    1. would be the main window with ImageButton.
    2. and the other class that returns the selected images to the first class. (Contains the function that calls the gallery or camera, cuts the image, the other “onActivityResult” function that returns the image address, who asked for the picture).
So far everything works correctly.

Problem Description: The problem arises from the second image selected. when the second class returns everything to the first, it is as if the second image is stored in the same memory space as the first (erasing everything previously), and if I select the third image, it deletes the second and only remains the third and henceforth. What I want to do is select the images and have them all seen at the same time (usable) to send to a server.

Solutions I tried:

> 1. After days of searching, the suggestion was to make several returns on “onActivityResult” so that it returned the result of selecting
>      images separately, I couldn't find anything that worked, the
>      explanations I found were only halfway (including the official
>      documentation does not detail the steps to control the various returns
>      of the function, is very superficial), could not control the separate
>      pointing of the images.

```
switch (requestCode){
                case (1000):
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(TirarFoto1.this, RegistrarAutomovelDuasRodas.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("class", classname);
                    intent1.putExtra("imageview", imageview);
                    intent1.putExtra("pathimage", pathimage);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    break;
                case (2000):
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(TirarFoto1.this, RegistrarAutomovelDuasRodas.class);
                    intent2.putExtra("class", classname);
                    intent2.putExtra("imageview", imageview);
                    intent2.putExtra("pathimage", pathimage);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                case (3000):
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(TirarFoto1.this, RegistrarAutomovelDuasRodas.class);
                    intent3.putExtra("class", classname);
                    intent3.putExtra("imageview", imageview);
                    intent3.putExtra("pathimage", pathimage);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
```

> 2. I decided to save each image separately outside the “temporary cache” folder (where they are located), even with the “manifest”
>      permissions, nothing happens, permission is denied, so I couldn't even
>      create the new folder to save the images in it, as a result does not
>      save the selected images.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(TirarFoto1.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String.valueOf(imageUri))+"folderName");
                if (!file.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (success){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "creaty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Erro!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else {
                requestStoragePermisson();
            }
```

Result: The first solution did not work and the second did not work.
What I want: a model, a concrete way to help me, can anyone please help me with this? I have been stuck in this problem for a long time.

Comment: onActivityResult is a void function. So it does not return anything. Please edit your post and reword.

Comment: Show the onClick code at start of your post. Remove the permission check as we believe you will do that.

Comment: For every requestCode you start the same Registrar... intent. We see no difference. And what should it start exactly? Put all in your post please.

Comment: `after that I can crop the selected image.` And are you displaying it in 'the clickable photo'?

Comment: @blackapps , If "onActivityResult" returns a null value, what should I do? I already tested it without checking permissions, it went nowhere. and how do I request onActivityResult? yes, I'm showing her in the clickable photo.In case the photo was already edited and returned the final product that I will use, until then is quiet.

Comment: `If "onActivityResult" returns a null value,` Are you listening? Repeat: onActivityResult is a void function so it cannot return a value!. You better explain where you have that null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me to use ArthurHub-Android-Image-Cropper for cropped image, you can learn from this link

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki

hope this help

Edit:
i have a class using ArthurHub-Android-Image-Cropper  but from kotlin and i try to convert to java
like this

```
//for identify image
private Int imageNo;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //......

    //set button image 1
    final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_image1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // set image count to 1
            imageNo=1
            getImageClick()
        }
    });

    //set button image 2
    final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_image1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // set image count to 2
            imageNo=2
            getImageClick()
        }
    });

    //set button image 3
    final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_image1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // set image count to 3
            imageNo=3
            getImageClick()
        }
    });
}

//select image form camera or galery 
public void getImageClick() {
    CropImage.startPickImageActivity(this);
}

//this for Crope Image
private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
  CropImage.activity(imageUri)
    .start(this);
}

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //handle result from onGetimageClick(button for select image from camera or galery)
    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);
        //start Crope image
        startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
    }

    // handle result of CropImageActivity
    else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
        switch (imageNo){
            case (1):
                //here you have resultUri for save image or preview as image1
                break;
            case (2):
                //here you have resultUri for save image or preview as image1
            case (3):
                //here you have resultUri for save image or preview as image1
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget to add manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

Hope this help

Comment: ,you did not understand. cut the image I already did, and I get the return the way I want, the problem is when I select the second image, it gives the impression that both use the same memory address, because when I select the next (cropped) image, the old image (the first selected) is deleted and the second is in the imageview. I want to keep all selected.

Comment: I already refuted this documentation, I even sent a message to the creator and he recommended me to ask for help here on this site.

Comment: Im so sory for miss understand, if that, are u save image at same name file?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you. I save the image address in a variable when I get it in first class.

Comment: at this class i use 1 class for handle  get image then crop image and save image at onActivityResult

Comment: fantastic my friend! It worked, just had a problem, when I chose the second image he automatically put the second image in the third without me having chosen. I will try to find out why.

Comment: My mistake, the "breack" was missing. thanks so much for the help man, hug.

Comment: Ok friend, Glad I could help you